# I am getting this problem when I open an existing project

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, gradle, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradl e-plugin:1.3.50.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradl e-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradl e-plugin-1.3.50.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradl e-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradl e-plugin-1.3.50.jar
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradl e-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradl e-plugin-1.3.50.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradl e-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradl e-plugin-1.3.50.jar
> Required by:
> project :

Answer (score 0):

The plugin `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50` is not found in `google()` repository, and the `jcenter()` repository is deprecated now. In your level settings.gradle (and root build.gradle), in the `repositories {}` block, replace `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()`.